# Unwanted Exception squelching during VS2008 debugging

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, exception, .net-3.5, sqldatareader

Is there a way to force `SqlDataReader` to throw exceptions?  There seems to be a very problematic behavior with it where `SqlDataReader` will have an exception and cause the function it's in to end prematurely without throwing an exception, specifically when it tries to read `isDBNull` values.

(5/10/2013) EDIT:  On further reflection, it looks like be behavior of `Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions` that is silently catching the exception.

And apparently the exception squelching only occurs while debugging--I ran a release build and the exception definitely surfaced there.  So it's only a property of Visual Studio debugging apparently.

(5/14/2013) EDIT2:  Found similar catching in debug without a try/catch block behavior with a SqlDataReader index not matching the column name.  IndexOutOfRangeException only surfacing if "break on all exceptions" debug settings used.

More details:

```
Public Function GetData() As DataObj
    Dim sqlConn As New SqlConnection(ConnectionSettings.DBCon)
    Dim sqlCommand As New SqlCommand("an_sp", sqlConn)
    Dim sqlReader As SqlDataReader
    Dim dataObject As New DataObj

    sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

    sqlCommand.Connection.Open()
    sqlReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader

    While sqlReader.Read
        With dataObject
            'Exception thrown here in debugging
            .DateField = sqlReader("DateField")

        End With
    End While

    Return dataObject
End Function
```

System.InvalidCastException occurred
  Message="Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'Date' is not valid."
  Source="Microsoft.VisualBasic"
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToDate(Object Value)
       at DataAccess.MyDAO.GetData() in C:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\VS 2008 Projects\General\DataAccess\DataAccess\MyDAO.vb:line 603
  InnerException:

Comment: Can you post some code we have a gander at?

Comment: Updated with more data